# How can i get the common value from same array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to get the common value as well as different value from same array

For example :

```
$array1 = array(1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,7,8,9,10);
```

And I want the array as

```
$array1 = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
```

Can anyone give me the idea to bring the array like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you try

```
$array1 = array(1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,7,8,9,10); 
$array1 = array_unique($array1);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Answer (score 2):

Use array unique

```
array_unique($array1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$array1 = array(1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,7,8,9,10);
$array = array_unique($array1);
print_r($array )
```

see [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) . It will remove the Duplicate values from  array

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
 $array1 = array(1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,7,8,9,10);

 $unique_array=array_unique($array1);

 print_r($unique_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

use array_unique(). It reduceds an array.