# Get common number of values in a single array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to get the common number of values from an array. Please check the following array

```
array(111) {
  [0]=> int(1807)
  [1]=> int(3013)
  [2]=> int(2989)
  [3]=> int(1815)
  [4]=> int(2993)
  [5]=> int(1807)
  [6]=> int(2999)
  [7]=> int(3003)
  [8]=> int(1815)
  [9]=> int(3009)
  [10]=> int(3013)
}
```

As you can see following are common items:

- 0 and 5
- 1 and 10
- 3 and 8

I need the output like:

```
array(1807, 3013, 1815)
```

Just to be clear [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) wont work here, because it removes the duplicates from an array. I dont want to remove duplicates, I want to remove the non duplicate ones ..

Comment: do you mean, recurring number?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i get the common value from same array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16009753/how-can-i-get-the-common-value-from-same-array)

Comment: @mega6382 yes, that is the common one.

Comment: @LearningROR No that will remove the duplicate values from an array.

Comment: @ZainSohail If any of the provided solution worked then please accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use simply `array_unique` and `array_diff_assoc` function . here is an example

```
$array = [1,2,3,1,2];
$unique_array = array_unique($array);
$array = array_diff_assoc($array, $unique_array);
$array = $array_unique($array);
print_r($array);
```

output :

```
Array ( [3] => 1 [4] => 2 )
```

Comment: An additional array_unique is required after the diff else  you'll have multiple values for the same item, try it with: 
 [1807, 1 , 222, 222, 3013, 2989, 1807, 1807, 2989, 3012]

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
$arr = array(
    1807,
    3013,
    2989,
    1815,
    2993,
    1807,
    2999,
    3003,
    1815,
    3009,
    3013,
);

$arr2 = $arr;

$recurring = [];

foreach($arr2 as $key => $value)
{
    unset($arr2[$key]);
    if(in_array($value, $arr2) && !in_array($value, $recurring))
    {
        $recurring[] = $value;
    }
}

var_dump($recurring);
```

this will give you all of the recurring values from your inside the `$recurring` variable. But be sure that you don't iterate the main array through the loop instead copy it like `$arr2 = $arr;`

Comment: Its working for 2 number of duplicates. But not working for 3 number of duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, if this could be easier done with php build in array functions, but a simple for loop with two temp array vars, will do the job to.

```
$array = [1,1,2,3,4,4];
$t = [];
$double = [];
foreach ($array as $item) {
    if (isset($t[$item])) {
        $double[$item] = true;
    }
    $t[$item] = true;
}
$values = array_keys($double);
```

Thought again about an other solution without the explicit loop and came up with this one, using `array_reduce`

```
$array = [1,1,2,3,4,4];
$values = [];
sort($array);
array_reduce($array, function($last, $current) use (&$values) {
    return $last == $current ? $values[$current] = $current : $current;
}, false);

print_r($values);
```

Answer (score 0):

All you want are the duplicates.

Try this:

```
$duplicates= array();
foreach(array_count_values($arr) as $val => $c)
    if($c > 1) $duplicates[] = $val;
return $duplicates;
```